# ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible() in different .jar files lead to java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Exception on openJDK

Tags: spring, maven, java

i have the following problem: we raised our application from java6 with tomcat6 to java8 with tomcat8. Starting the application on our local machines with Oracle Java 8 worked witouth problem. But on our server we get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We investigated the problem and the ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible() Method is provided by spring-core-2.0.8.jar and org.springframework.core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar

Our server is running OpenJDK 8 instead of Oracle Java 8 and it seems like the application tries to use makeAccessible() from the spring-core-2.0.8.jar instead of the org.springframework.core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar. When we delete the spring-core-2.0.8.jar in our lib Folder the application starts without a problem. Unfortunately the spring-core-2.0.8.jar comes as a maven transitive dependency from a maven hibernate dependency, therefore we need this jar.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks in advance, best regards

Comment: Typical 'jar hell' problem. You need to analyze your dependency tree, find out who pulls `spring-core-2.0.8` as a transitive dependency and block it.

Comment: I already did this, but like i said the spring-core-2.0.8.jar comes as a dependency with hibernate but i cannot exclude spring-core in maven because it is necessary for hibernate.

Comment: Yes you can and you should as you are now effectively  mixing spring versions and you should never mix versions of a framework. You have a core version which is 3.0.4 . Use that. All your versions should match.

Comment: What M. Deinum said. Having different versions of the same library on your classpath (especially such a huge difference) can cause some very hard to track problems (as different OSes/JVM versions can load jars in a different order). Use only newer version. If your Hibernate would not work with spring 3, then you need to upgrade Hibernate or downgrade Spring.